# How to Filter a JavaScript React table based on DropDown Box Selection

Tags: java

I have a table with football player data such as wins, losses etc. I also have a drop down box of player names. I want to be able to select a player name from the drop down box and filter the table to only show the data from that table. I have tried using the curr

```
class F
      this.state = { footballStats: [], selectedPlayers: []}
    }

     componentDidMount() {    
       fetch('http://localhost:3000/footballstats')
           .then((data) => data.json())
           .then((data) => this.setState( { footballStats: data, selectedPlayers: data } ));
           //.then((data) => this.setState( { footballStats: _.sortBy(this.state.footballStats, 'L') } ));

    }

  getSelectedPlayers(player) {
    if (!player) {
      this.setState({selectedPlayers: this.state.footballStats});
    }ayer;   
        })]})
    }
  }
    render() {
        let names = this.state.footballStats;
        let optionItems = names.map((item) =>
        <option key={item.NAME}>{item.NAME}</option>
        );

              <select onChange={(e) => this.getSelectedPlayers(e)}> {optionItems}
              </select>
              <br></br>
              <br></br>

          <table border={1}>
            <tbody>
              <tr><th></th><th>Code</th><th>Player</th><th>W</th><th>L</th> </tr>
              {this.state.selectedPlayers.map((item) => {
                return (<tr key={item.TEAMCODE}</td><td>{item.NAME}</td><td>{item.W}</td><td>{item.L}</td><td></tr>);
              })}
            </tbody>
      );
    }
}

  ReactDOM.render(<FootballStats/>, document.getElementById('root'));

{
    "footballStats": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "NAME": "Phil Jones",
            "TEAMCODE": "MNU",
            "W":  "17
        },
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getSelectedPlayers(e) {
    if (!!e.target.value) { //if the user selects the empty (the !! is a cast to boolean)
      this.setState({selectedPlayers: this.state.footballStats});
    }
    else {
      this.setState({selectedPlayers: [this.state.footballStats.find((p) => {
          return p.NAME = e.target.value;   
        })]})
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. The player name now changes, but the rest of the data does not update in the table. So it will show one players name with the Wins and Losses from another player.

Answer (score 0):

`Error is you are not filtering and updating selectedPlayers array based on previousState and selected Player`. This is the working solution of your question.

```js
class FootballStats extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { footballStats: [], selectedPlayers: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let data = {
      footballStats: [
        {
          ID: 1,
          NAME: "Phil Jones",
          TEAMCODE: "MNU",
          W: "17",
          L: "2"
        },
        {
          ID: 2,
          NAME: "Chris Smalling",
          TEAMCODE: "MNU",
          W: "20",
          L: "4"
        },
        {
          ID: 3,
          NAME: "Luke Shaw",
          TEAMCODE: "MNU",
          W: "12",
          L: "7"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.setState({ footballStats: data.footballStats });
  }

  getSelectedPlayers(player) {
    let playerName = player.target.value;
    let isPlayerSeleted = true;
    this.state.selectedPlayers.forEach(player => {
      if(player.NAME === playerName)
        isPlayerSeleted = false;
    });
    if (isPlayerSeleted) {
      let updatedArray = this.state.footballStats.filter(
        p => p.NAME === playerName
      );
      this.setState(prevState => {
        let selectedPlayers = [...updatedArray, ...prevState.selectedPlayers];
        return { selectedPlayers };
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    let names = this.state.footballStats;
    let optionItems = names.map(item => (
      <option key={item.NAME}>{item.NAME}</option>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <select onChange={e => this.getSelectedPlayers(e)}>
          {" "}
          {optionItems}
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        {this.state.selectedPlayers.length > 0 ? (
          <table border={1}>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Player</th>
                <th>W</th>
                <th>L</th>
              </tr>
              {this.state.selectedPlayers.map(item => {
                return (
                  <tr key={item.TEAMCODE}>
                    <td>{item.TEAMCODE}</td>
                    <td>{item.NAME}</td>
                    <td>{item.W}</td>
                    <td>{item.L}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FootballStats />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```